# Как осуществить самый простой sql join не нарушая принципов DDD и Clean Architecture?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, ddd

Есть две сущности `User` и `Project`. В `Project` вторичный ключ на `User` тоесть на создателей этих проектов. Нужно вытащить даные о проектах и их создателях и передать их на фронт. В итоге получается, что в сущности *проекта* есть вложенная сущность *пользователя*, которая относится вообще к другому домену.
Вот так выглядят данные:

```
[
{
    id:1, 
    name: 'Project1', 
    description: 'Any', 
    creationDate: '', 
    ownerId:123, 
    owner:{
         id: 123,
         firstName:'John',
         lastName:'Doe',
         dob:''
    }
},
...
]
```

Как пропустить даные о владельцах проектов через сущность `User` не нарушая приципа слабой связности вообще не приходит в голову. По своей сути `entity` пользователя внутри `entity` проекта это уже **нарушение** этого принципа. 
Почитал об Aggregate Root, вроде что-то подходящее, но как это применить в этом случае?

Comment: На фронт передаются не сущности, а модель, содержащая в себе необходимую информацию. Фронт в итоге не имеет понятия, откуда была взята эта информация: из одной, из двух или множества таблиц, из файла(ов), из другого сервиса...

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, понятно что на фронте неважно откуда данные, но я о том как грамотно построить все на бэке и как наладить общение между доменами.

Comment: Вам следует познакомиться с CQRS. Если вы делаете join, то, наверняка, это запрос на чтение данных, это query-side в архитектуре приложения. И здесь применять паттерны DDD не требуется. Агрегаты существуют только на стороне команд.

Comment: должно быть User>Projects[] , а не наоборот, как у вас сейчас

Answer (score 0):

1. В классе-сервисе делаете запрос в домен Project, получаете проекты.
2. По айдишникам owner'ов делаете запрос в другой домен - получаете данные о людях.
3. А потом либо передаёте структуру "Project с Owner внутри" прямо на фронт (массивом, JSON'ом и т.д.) или если нужно - создаёте класс ProjectOwnersViewData и отдаёте результат как объект.

Запросы в БД можно кэшировать по id.